# Create db connections before run aiohttp loop

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

is it not mistake create some connections (to DB, AMQP etc) before run `web.run_app` in aiohttp.
Some example:

```
async def init_app():
    app = web.Application()

    app['db'] = await create_db_connection()
    app['amqp'] = await create_amqp_connection()

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(init_app())
    web.run_app(app)
```

It works, but I'm not sure about is this right or not.
I know about `app.startup` but I have I'd like to handle all connection's errors before start main application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct until you don't care about closing resources before the server exit.

Most people don't, that's fine.

Otherwise `app.cleanup` signal should be used.

Comment: I use app.cleanapp for closing resourses, sure. I